# Python tcp socket with ssl encryption [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, tcp, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a Windows 10 computer and a Windows 10 virtual machine. I´ve created a tcp socket server/client application which is secured via python ssl. My code looks like this:

Server:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.set_ciphers('ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384') 
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="cert.pem", keyfile="prKey.pem")

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((ip, port))
    
ssocket = context.wrap_socket(tcpsock, server_side=True)
```

Client:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_verify_locations("cert.pem")

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_ip)
```

My friend created an official certificate to use for my server-side authentication. This was created and validated via OpenSSL if I understand correctly. However, when I try to connect to the running server with my client I receive the following error message (client-side error):

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
```

I put the certificate + matching private key (pem format) on the virtual machine and I have a copy of the certificate (pem format) on my localhost.

I also have a certificate in cer file format, which I installed to the root windows certificate store (client and server side).

Since this did not work I kept researching and found out about the `certifi` package. I installed it and found by using`print(certifi.where())` a `cacert.pem` file. Which contained multiple certificates. I added my friends certificate to that file via copy and paste, safe it but I still receive the same error.

Now I´m seriously kinda lost about what is wrong. When I disable `context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED` my code is working just fine, but I really want server-side authentication for my code..

Comment: Is 'cert.pem' self-signed? Are 'cert.pem' used in server code and client code the same or different?

Comment: Also, if possible, provide the output of following command for each cert you are using here: openssl x509 -in <cert_file_path> -noout -subject -issuer

Comment: cert.pem are the same, and they are CA certified not self-signed. The command you posted prints information about my friend's company.

Comment: "cert.pem" on server code will contain the server (leaf certificate) and its issuer and its issuer's issuer and so on except the root certificate (which is self-signed). And, "cert.pem" on client code should contain only the root certificate which was skipped above. All the intermediate certificate (probably root cert also) should be provided by the entity which issued your server certificate. If not already familar with cert chains and chain validation, read upon it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the client's code to:

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.ip)
```

This way I don't have to hand a certificate file manually over. Instead, it seems like my Windows root certificate library gets scanned and finds my VM´s certificate automatically (since I installed the .cer file).

On the server side, I simply had to pass the certificate.cer file instead of the pem format.

```
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="cert.cer", keyfile="prKey.pem")
```